# How to change the format of a date field in SQL?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a date field in one of my tables that's formatted like this: 20220212.

I want to CAST it like this: 2022/02/12 but a simple CAST(DATE_FIELD AS DATE) doesn't seem to work. ANyone know how I can achieve this with SQL in Snowflake?

Thanks!

Comment: Please Confirm the object is a date in the database and not string.  And don't mix up the data type stored in the database with the "FORMAT" or "Mask" of the object when presenting on screen.  Note there's a difference between a "Date object" and how that date object is rendered on a screen.  Why?  Date's can be MM/DD/YYYY in some regions, YYYY/MM/DD in others and DD/MM/YYYY in still others; and a wide variety inbetween. A date object can be masked to display in a desired format.  A string object must first be converted to a date object then the mask can be applied to render the desired format

Comment: Date _column_, not field. (But a date has a year field, a month field and a day field.)

Answer (score 1):

Please try `to_date()`

```
to_date(DATE_FIELD, 'YYYY/MM/DD')
```

[Documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_date.html)

Comment: TO_DATE doesn't seem to work in Snowflake

Comment: Sorry @JustineMit. I doesn't have access to snowflake environment. I found it in snowflake documentation. This should work if the column is of type date.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Select to_date('20220212','YYYYMMDD')::date as dt, to_char(dt,'YYYY/MM/DD') ;
```

[image]